# Create a jar file containing the unit test

Tags: java, maven, junit

I need to develop a Junit test framework for a project. It should be structured in such a way that all written Junit tests are available in a jar file and that a new jar file can simply be added for new tests. So it is a program with an interface where students add their exercises or their classes and then say which exercise it is and the program performs the correct JUnit tests. How can I do this or does anyone know a better idea how to do it instead of using jar files?

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck doing this?

Comment: At the Idea how i can I test external Classes with Junit Test that are inside of a Jar-File. Like the first Question is how I put my Testclasses in a Jar-File.

Comment: That's just like building any jar file.